# How to tag multi architecture docker image and push the newly tagged image?

Tags: docker, docker-image, buildx, docker-push, docker-tag

I'm trying to achieve re tagging of docker images via docker command.

Basically I need to do the below steps to achieve my goal:

1)Pull an existing multi architecture image from private registry.

2)Tag it with new name (e.g: tag imagename-test to imagename-final)

3)And push the newly tagged image back to private registry again.

So I have tried the below command:

```
docker buildx build --tag {registry name/repository}/imagename-test --tag {registry name/repository}/imagename-final \
-- pull -- platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64 \
-- push .
```

Here the image is getting pushed with both tags.But I need to tag imagename-test to imagename-final and only need to push imagename-final to the registry.

Usually we do,

```
docker pull imagename-test
docker tag imagename-test imagename-final
docker push imagename-final
```

Any suggestions to achieve this by using only docker buildx commands for multi architecture images?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `docker buildx imagetools` to re-tag an image index, i.e:

```
docker buildx imagetools create -t imagename-final imagename-test
```

More info about imagetools create [here](https://github.com/docker/buildx/blob/master/docs/reference/buildx_imagetools_create.md)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `docker buildx imagetools create`, there are multiple tools that would do this without needing to pull the image or risk changing the digest on the image. Google has crane, RedHat has skopeo, and I have regclient.

```
crane copy $src $dest

skopeo copy docker://$src docker://$dest

regctl image copy $src $dest
```

With each of those, the tooling only needs to pull the top level manifest, which is typically a couple kb of JSON data, and none of the layers, making it much faster than a docker pull. (You can often download these tools faster than you can pull an image.)